# Grep - find and replace

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep

I am trying to replace a hex code in my stylesheets to a variable - I am trying to do:

```
grep -rl '#e5f6fc' mydirectory | xargs sed -i 's/#e5f6fc/$highlight-blue/g'
```

I am assuming that the "#", "$" and "-" are doing something to cause this error. I tried to research how to type expressions with grep but I cant find anything to help me out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The error I get is:

**unterminated substitute in regular expression**

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing single quote in grep command, it should be:

```
grep -irl '#e5f6fc' mydirectory | xargs sed -i.bak 's/#e5f6fc/$highlight-blue/Ig'
```

PS: I made both grep and sed *ignore case*

Comment: My apologizes I may have deleted the quote when I was formatting it in stack overflow. I entered this: grep -irl '#e5f6fc' mydirectory  | xargs sed -i 's/#e5f6fc/$highlight-blue/g' and grep -rl '#e5f6fc' mydirectory  | xargs sed -i 's/#e5f6fc/$highlight-blue/g' and I still get 'unterminated substitute in regular expression'

Comment: @Jamie: What is your sed version? As that edited command of yours is working fine for me.

Comment: Can you try: `grep -irl '#e5f6fc' mydirectory | xargs sed -i.bak 's/\#e5f6fc/\$highlight-blue/g'`

Comment: I tried using the backslashes - but i will try again with the next commands you added.

Comment: Nothing was printed and nothing was replace - how do I found out the version I am running?

Comment: But you didn't get this: `unterminated substitute in regular expression` error? Can you post a sample of your input file? On what platform/OS are you trying this sed?

Comment: To find the version your are running: sed --version

Comment: anubhava, why did you add '.bak' after -i in sed ?

Comment: @adbar: Newer sed works with out an extension with `-i` but older sed versions needed an argument with `-i`.